# Delete `--_--.sparseimage`

Tags: linux, macos, osx-yosemite

I have a file named: `--_--.sparseimage`

This file was created by OSX Diskutil app,
but because the filename itself is troubling,
Diskutil cannot fill it with any data.

And I can't seem to make any new disk image
when this file still exist.

Here are the commands I've tried to delete this file:

- `rm -f -- --_--.sparseimage`
- `rm -f ./--_--.sparseimage`
- `rm -f ./'--_--.sparseimage'`
- `rm -f ./"--_--.sparseimage"`
- `rm -f ./'\-\-_\-\-.sparseimage'`
- `rm -f ./\-\-_\-\-.sparseimage`
- `find . -inum $inum -exec rm -- '{}' \;`
- `find . -inum $inum -delete`

They all failed with the same error (or variation of it):

```
--_--.sparseimage: Invalid argument
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that `rm -- './--_--.sparseimage'` should work, given you have the permission to delete that file.

Comment: The problem probably isn't the filename (after you've used eg. "--"); "Invalid argument" sounds like EINVAL, ie. an error return from the system call. Check special permissions on the file (eg. [ACLs](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/210925-strange-file-permission.html) and chattr if OSX has something like it). Filesystem corruption could also cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up restarting the computer.

Seems like Diskutil and/or several other system services are still having
a lock on that file.

After restarting, the first command succeeded in first try, the second
command should too, but won't bother to try.

Thx everyone for the reply :D